# Where is the executable to invoke the GNOME failed dialog on Fedora?

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome-shell

For the debugging purpose, I want to invoke the GTK failed dialog.

In Ubuntu, I can find the binary at `/usb/lib/gnome-session/gnome-session-failed`. Is the same function executable available in Fedora? I tried to search around but could not find it in the system.

- Fedora version: 18 (Spherical Cow)
- GNOME version: 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check files in a rpm package this way:

```
$ rpm -ql gnome-session | grep failed
/usr/lib/systemd/user/gnome-session-failed.service
/usr/lib/systemd/user/gnome-session-failed.target
/usr/libexec/gnome-session-failed
```

Seems for the version you are using there was not such executable and the fail dialog would run by doing : `gnome-session whale`.
See: https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-session/blob/e59b938c644a78236fd5ed9d708022be3b990ddc/gnome-session/main.c#L296

Comment: thanks. however, i got nothing from rpm -ql gnome-session | grep gailed
and i did not find gnome-session-failed.service in the directory you specified. any clue? I thought this is a default package which should be installed when I installed the OS. I might be wrong anyway.

Comment: Quite curios, I'm running Fedora 32. And just executed that before posting.

Comment: Mine is fedora 18, a very old version i know.

Comment: I wasn't even using Fedora then haha. I guess you can do a `find /usr -iname gnome-session-failed` , also maybe check  `/bin/` and `/lib/` or even `/`. Or go the the .ac files from the gnome version you are using. But if not found with `find`, will not be there.

Comment: I doubt if fedora uses the same name "gnome-session-failed" as ubuntu. I could not find this executable in my system after executing "find" command.

Comment: May have been called something else back then, in that gnome version, was that already > 3? can't remember. I do have the `gnome-session-failed` executable on the most recent Fedora version. I doubt you will find any supported info for surch old version.

Comment: Just updated my post and added fedora and gnome version.

Answer (score 1):

`gnome-session-failed` is not available in the version you mentioned.

you need to use `gnome-session` instead and specify with `-whale`.